# Category name in excel charts, using VBA without using any Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I'm wanting to do a chart where the ticks on the X axis are not numbers but texts. For the purpose of learning: monthes like "January, August, February, November" or "Apples, Bananas, Cars".

The trick is that I don't want these informations coming from any cells. It will be coded on Excel VBA.

Maybe it is very very easy. I just don't know HOW look for it. I've beeing trying for the last couple hours, but still nothing. Look that it isn't the label of the axis that I'm wanting to change, but every data pointed in the Y-axis will have it name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is easy. The series can also be filled with absolute values. In the chart, it will look like: `=SERIES("SeriesName",{2012\2013\2014\2015\2016\2017},{1\2\3\4\5\6},1)`

Comment: MP24.. but these values would have to be on the cells, right? I have some calculations on VBA, so I have to set them from VBA. For it, I don't want to use any cells, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly fill data into the chart using VBA without using cells

For e.g.

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "={4,5,6}"
```

would change the category data displayed to 4,5,6. You can generate any string you require programmatically and change it.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with data that looks like this:

[image]

You can set the axis labels using this line:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "={""Jan"",""Feb"",""Mar"",""Apr"",""May"",""Jun""}"
```

---

Full Example code:

```
Sub AddChart()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "={""Jan"",""Feb"",""Mar"",""Apr"",""May"",""Jun""}"
End Sub
```

---

Results:

[image]